# Lightning badges inside input

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, inputtext

I have an input field where people can write one or multiple email addresses. For now, when they are added I display a list of `lightning:button` with the selected ones but is does not look good at all.

I would like those added addresses to stack INSIDE the `lightning:input` as `buttons` or `badges` so the user can write at the right of them inside the `input`.

Something like this (**not working**):

```
  <lightning:input
    aura:id="email"
    type="email"
    label="a"
    name="a"
    multiple="{! true }"
  >
    <aura:iteration items="{! v.selectedEmails }" var="selectedEmail">
      <lightning:badge label="selectedEmail" />
    </aura:iteration>
  </lightning:input>
```

In fact I want it to work as it is for the tags insertion on Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

I don' t know if you can display the email addresses as a badge as you are typing along in the `lightning:input`.

But I'd suggest, displaying the list of addresses entered after you've typed it all in the input box.

Below is an example using [lightning:layout and lightning:layoutItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_layoutItem.htm).

Demo with static badges:

```
<div>
    Email addresses entered : 
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
            <lightning:badge label="Email1" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
            <lightning:badge label="Email2" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
            <lightning:badge label="Email3" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
</div>
enter code here
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: This is how it looks like]

Your code would be something like:

```
<div>
    Email addresses entered : 
    <lightning:layout>
        <aura:iteration items="{! v.selectedEmails }" var="selectedEmail">
            <lightning:badge label="{!selectedEmail}" />
         </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:layout>
</div>
```

Comment: You answer looks good but it is not what I expected: if they are too much items, the layout is broken at the right of the screen + I need to add an `onclick`event on it. ty anw